# Does Every Point Differentiable Function always equal to its Talyor Expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Below is the excerpt from the Wikipedia Page

"A function may not be equal to its Taylor series, even if its Taylor series converges at every point. A function that is equal to its Taylor series in an open interval (or a disc in the complex plane) is known as an analytic function in that interval."

Untill now I had always used talyor expansion over differential function and equate it with the original function.

Is there any possibility the taylor expansion deviate from its orginal functiom while the function is every point differentiable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function

Comment: It means the title of OP is false

Comment: The Fabius function: https://mathoverflow.net/a/17285/4678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f:\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$ given by
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x} & x >0, \\ 0 &x \leq 0,\end{cases}$$
is $C^\infty$ in $\mathbf{R}$ (one can show this by induction). But $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k \geq 0.$

Therefore, the Taylor series of $f$ is identically zero in any neighborhood of the origin, so $f$ can't be equal to its Taylor series.

Comment: What does c^infty denote for?

Comment: For $k \geq 0$, the notation $C^k$ is the set of $k$-times continuously differentiable functions (the $k$'th derivative is continuous), and $C^\infty = \cup_{k=0}^\infty C^k$ is the set of infinitely differentiable functions. An example of a function in $C^1$ but not $C^2$ is the antidervative of the absolute value function.

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult to construct examples of functions that are differentiable everywhere but analytic nowhere.  Basically, you take the sum of a series of "bump" functions with coefficients that go to $0$ rapidly enough.

Comment: This question is off topic from op but what it conventionally mean "analytic"?

Comment: An analytic function, in every single context, is a function that is pointwisedly equal to *some* power series in *some* disc of convergence. Of course, power series are infinitely differentiable in their radius of convergence (it takes a bit of work to prove this, but it's reasonable to believe given its true for their close cousins, polynomials), and thus analytic functions are infinitely differentiable. As RI has pointed out, the converse need not be true. Enter the world of complex analysis and tweak your definition of differentiability and you get the other direction!

Comment: Thx for kind explanation

Comment: More correctly: a function is analytic at a point if it is given as a power series in some neighborhood of that point. An analytic function is one which is analytic on its domain.